# Error while creating layout template in codigniter

Tags: php, layout, codeigniter-3

I have two layout templates in my project and always loading first template. How to load second template also.

In main Usercontroller how to differentiate them. They are,

### Learncontroller.php

```
class Learncontroller extends Usercontroller{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model("Usermodel","",true);    
    }

    public function index(){
        $id=$this->session->userdata('cp_userid');
        $menuActive= "learning";
        $data['menuActive'] = $menuActive;
        $userdetails=$this->Usermodel->getuserdetails($id);
        $data['userdetails']=$userdetails;
        $result=$this->Usermodel->currentlearningcourses($id);
        $data['details']=$result;
        $data['content']=$this->load->view("user/currentlearningcourses",$data,true);

        $data['title']='My Courses';
        //$this->load->view("user/layout",$data);

        $headerContent = $this->load->view("user/layout",$data,true);
        $this->render($headerContent);
    }
}
```

### Unitcontroller.php

```
class Unitcontroller extends Usercontroller{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model("Usermodel","",true);
    }

    public function courselearn($id){
        $r=$this->Usermodel->getsectiontopic($id);
        $data['topicId']=$id;
        $data['topicQ']=$r;
        $data['video']=$this->input->post("id");
        $data['id']=$id;
        $data['content']=$this->load->view("user/unit_content",$data, true);

        $courselearnheaderContent = $this->load->view("user/courselearn_layout",$data,true);
        $this->render($courselearnheaderContent);
    }
}
```

Learncontroller and Unitcontroller has separate layouts but always loading `protected $layout = 'user/layout';`. How to load this `'user/courselearn_layout';` when control comes from Unitcontroller.

### Usercontroller.php

```
protected $layout = 'user/layout';
protected $courselearn_layout = 'user/courselearn_layout';

protected function render($headerContent) {
    $view_data = array( 'headerContent' => $headerContent);
    $this->load->view($this->layout);
}
```

Always loading first page. How to make load the second page also please help me.